# Problems reading a file in, and editing certain contents of it

Tags: python, file

So I have a file with
**first name**(space)**last name**(tab)**a grade** as such.

Example
Wanda Barber    96

I'm having trouble reading this in as a list and then editing the number.

My current code is,

```
def TopStudents(n):

    original = open(n)
    contents = original.readlines()
    x = contents.split('/t')

    for y in x[::2]:
        y - 100 
        if y > 0: (????)
```

Here is the point where I'm confused. I am just trying to get the first and last names of students who scored over 100%. I thought of creating a new list for students that meet this qualification, but I'm not sure how I would write the corresponding first and last name. I know I need to take the stride of every other location in the list, as odd will always be the first and last names.  Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Your indenting is broken, please edit and fix.

Comment: Did it work? If it did, could you upvote and mark it as correct? Otherwise, please tell me what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code:
- The open file must be closed (#1)
- Must be made a function call using to call it (#2)
- The split used is using the forwardslash (/) instead of the backslash () (#3)
- The way you decided to loop through your for loop is not optimal if you are looking to access all the members (#4)
- The for loops end in a `:` (#5)
- You must store the result of that calculation somewhere (#6)

```
def TopStudents(n):
    original = open(n) #1
    contents = original.readlines #2
    x = contents.split('/t') #3

    for y in x[::2] #4, #5
        y - 100 #6
        if y > 0:
```

That said, a fixed version could be:

```
original = open(n, 'r')
for line in original:
    name, score = line.split('\t')
    # If needed, you could split the name into first and last name:
    # first_name, last_name = name.split(' ')
    # 'score' is a string, we must convert it to an int before comparing to one, so...
    score = int(score)
    if score > 100:
        print("The student " + name + " has the score " + str(score))
original.close() #1 - Closed the file
```

*Note: I have focused on readability with several commentary to help you understand the code.*

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really test the code, just wrote it to help it solve the problem. Tested and also fixed another typos

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use ‘with open()’ because it closes the file automatically. I used a txt with comma separations for simplicity for me, but you can just replace the comma with \t.

```
def TopStudents():
    with open('temp.txt', 'r') as original:
        contents = list(filter(None, (line.strip().strip('\n') for line in original)))
    x = list(part.split(',') for part in contents)
    for y in x:
        if int(y[1]) > 100: 
            print(y[0], y[1])
TopStudents()
```

This opens and loads all lines into contents as a list, removing blank lines and line breaks. Then it separates into a list of lists.

You then iterate through each list in x, looking for the second value (y[1]) which is your grade. If the int() is greater than 100, print each segment of y.